# React Higher Order Components syntax

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, recompose

### Overview

I am having a hard time understanding the syntax I am finding on the net when it comes to wrapping react components with higher order components in order to access props.

The following example (which works) I am to wrapping the component with

**`withFireStore => ReduxForms => Connect => Component`**

```
export default withFirestore(
    reduxForm({
        form: "createStudents", validate
    })(connect(
          mapStateToProps,
          mapDispatchToProps)(CreateStudentsForm))
);
```

#### Background of what I am trying to do

Ultimately I am trying to access props through a Validate function I am using as part of the revalidate.js library. When following the solution [from this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197297/validate-dynamically-generated-form-in-react-using-redux-form-and-revalidate), I do not get the props mapped to state from ownProps. I believe this is due to how I an ordering my Higher order components.

### Problem

I actually need ReduxForm wrapped by the connect so it can access props I am mapping from redux state.

**`withFireStore => Connect => ReduxForms => Component`**

> Attempt 1

```
export default withFirestore(
    (connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps
        )
        (reduxForm({
            form: "createStudents", validate
        }))
        (CreateStudentsForm)
    )
);
```

Error

`Cannot call a class as a function`

I thought i had the brackets in the wrong spots, but when I shift them like so I get

> Attempt #2

```
export default withFirestore(
    (connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps
        )
        (reduxForm({
            form: "createStudents", validate
        })
        (CreateStudentsForm))
    )
);
```

Error

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect.`

#### Questions

1. I find chaining functions like this very confusing, is there a better way to write this?
2. How do I write this so reduxFrom will be wrapped by connect which should give me access to the props within my forms.

---

## Added to question:

#### CreateStudentForm.js imports

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
import {compose} from 'redux';
import { Container, Form, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import MaterialIcon from '../../material-icon/materialIcon';
import { withFirestore } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TextInput from "../../forms/textInput";
import { combineValidators, isRequired } from "revalidate";
import { setupStudentForm } from '../../../store/actions/students';
```

The CreateStudentForm is imported into a Stateful component called modal.js

#### Modal.js imports

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Modal, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import CreateClassForm from "../createClass/createClassForm";
import EditClassForm from "../editClass/editClassForm";
import EditHomeworkForm from "../editHomework/editHomeworkForm";
import CreateHomeworkForm from "../createHomework/createHomeworkForm";
import CreateStudentsForm  from "../createStudents/createStudentsForm";
import { withFirestore } from "react-redux-firebase";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `compose`, sth like:

```
export default compose(
  withFirestore, 
  reduxForm({
    form: "createStudents", validate
  }),
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
)(CreateStudentsForm);
```

Comment: Thats much cleaner, I will begin to use that, however i still get:
```Uncaught Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect.```
I am wondering if this is a problem with my imports. I will edit my question to show the imports for this component and the component thats importing this one

Comment: What do you mean, import orders or the Higher Order Components? Do you see what i need to fix?

Comment: I've updated order of HOCs within compose - check this